# Windows 10: /usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows-10, git-bash

Under windows 10, Im receiving

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory
```

in gitbash, when trying to execute, eg, bpmake command.

Python added to PATH (version 3.8)

What was missed in config?

Comment: What's the result of `whereis python3`?

Comment: bash: whereis: command not found  // trying figure out dependency for "whereis"

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` is not a Windows command as far as I'm aware. The script you are trying to run seems to be tailored to a unix-like OS.

Comment: Assuming git-bash has an overall standard setup (other than missing `whereis`): how did you install Python 3?

Comment: installation package from python org

Comment: Still: how? Inside git-bash, or did you run an executable in Windows?

Comment: executable in windows (.exe file from python org, latest version)

Comment: i installed whereis, and it writes "python3.dll is not a valid Win32 application" when im trying "whereis python3"

Comment: Try installing it through git-bash; though if that's anywhere near a unix-like virtual machine, you may need to compile from source, which is not something you want to do.

Comment: Alternatively, consider using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), if you need unix-like behaviour. *Or*, do everything Windows-style instead (that is, not using git-bash, but a Windows command prompt or similar; and Windows-style PATH settings).

Comment: well, finally i just installed ubuntu and successfuly started using it. anyway, if smth could be done for this under Windows, note this pls.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10: I installed python39 next to python38. I uninstalled python39 due to mishmash on my system. python3 stopped to work.

So as workaround I copied python.exe in C:\Python38\ to python3.exe.
Not great, not terrible.

where python3 output in git-bash:

```sh
$ where python3
C:\Python38\python3.exe
```

```sh
$ /usr/bin/env python3
Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```